# Listen to custom events from other Controllers in Spine.js

Tags: spine.js

I have created a Spine Controller and I want to trigger a custom event 'Create' from inside one of it's methods. 
Then I would like another Spine Controller to listen for that event. 
How is this possible using Spine.js's custom event methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Custom events don't have to be global. You can can trigger/bind events per controller instance, but not per controller class.  For instance

```
class PresenterController extends Spine.Controller
  giveSpeech: (message) ->
    @trigger("speech",message)

class App extends Spine.Controller
  addKeynote: ->
    @speaker = new PresenterController
    @speaker.bind("speech",@listen)
  listen: (message) =>
    alert("I heard " + message)
```

But you can't get something like PresenterController.bind("speech")

The reason is that Model uses `@extend Event`, which adds methods to the *class*, but Controller uses `@include Event`, which adds methods to the *instance*. Model achieves the appearance of having instance bindings because it defines its own implementations of trigger, bind, and unbind

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger events in Spine like this

```
Spine.trigger "Create"
```

In you're other Controller you can bind the event to a method like this

```
Spine.bind "Create", @create
```

You have to define a method with the name create in this Controller:

```
create: =>
  # Create action
```

Because the custom events are global I would suggest using the controllers name as a prefix.
You could use ControllerName:Create for example:

```
Spine.trigger "ControllerName:Create"
```